# How do I stop visual studio checking out the web.config?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, web-config

I want to make changes to my web.config file but I dont want to check it out (as I really dont want to accidently check it in).

How can I do this? I unchecked 'read-only' in the file properties but this didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want/need to make changes to it? If it is to do some personal configuration, like which database to develop against, the common way to handle this is to check in a `.config.template` file, and leave the actual `.config` file out of source control altogether. Then, in a pre-build step, check if the file exists and if not, copy from the template. That way, every developer has his/her personal copy of that file.

Comment: I work in a large company and I cant make this change, good advice but I had already thought of that and the answer was a clear resounding corporate NO. :-)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2010? Then use web.config transforms, and have a "Local" configuration, which would give you a web.local.config to play with (and maybe not check in).

Comment: @JohnSaunders is right, this is a great way to do it.  We do that and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Using local config doesnt work. VS never transfrorms the web config for local debug even if I tell it to use that. Only publishing transforms the web.config

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable checking out files when you start editing them. This can be done via the source control part of the Visual Studio Configuration dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) in which you can generate the local web.config based on some rules, so each developer has its own local customized web.config - or all devs use the same web.config that is different than the one you ship.